# Node.js Express: Execute hook on every HTTP request, before app.get() and app.post()?

Tags: node.js, express

I don't want to put an authentication function at the top of every `app.get()`, how can I execute code on every request, before `app.get()`?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Set up a middleware before your routes:

```
function myMiddleware (req, res, next) {
   if (req.method === 'GET') { 
     // Do some code
   }

   // keep executing the router middleware
   next()
}

app.use(myMiddleware)

// ... Then you load the routes
```

Comment: Wow, that's perfect. I looked this up and the only answers I found were hacking core files, or overwriting the res.send function... I've never heard of `next()`, I'll have to look it up.

Comment: Why is there a comment that says `Run once, when server is started` just above all the middleware, if it runs on every request?

Answer (score 7):

You can also do:

```
app.all('*', auth.requireUser);
```

Comment: indeed it is not your standard way of using middleware.

Comment: can you specify the routes in this for `auth.requireUser` ?