# Node.js Express3 - Middleware to add render data to all render requests

Tags: node.js, express

Is it possible through express middleware or another method to add render data (the second option in `res.render`) to each call in the apps routes.

My app is using passport for authentication and I would like a middleware to always append the user information to each rendered template.

Currently each of my calls to `res.render` look similar to. I would like to remove the `user : req.user` and add that to a middleware function.

```
// Page 1
res.render("somepage1",{data : "somepage1", user : req.user});

// Page 2
res.render("somepage2",{data : "somepage2", user : req.user});
```

Comment: related?: [Execute hook on every HTTP request, before app.get() and app.post()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106300)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Express does provide [`app.locals`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.locals) and [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.locals), which it [automatically merges](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/3.1.0/lib/application.js#L467-474) with explicit locals passed in to `render` by a route handler.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.user = req.user;
    next();
});
```

Alternatively, you could hot patch the `render` function.  I'd avoid this since it's extra overhead, but if for some reason you needed to pass information not available before your route handler runs, it's an option:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var render = res.render;
    res.render = function(view, locals, cb) {
        if (typeof locals == 'object') locals.user = req.user;
        render.call(res, view, locals, cb);
    };
    next();
});
```

Comment: First thing I tried, does not work. res.render is part of an object which that method breaks.

Comment: You have to preserve `render`'s context via [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Comment: I see, then I guess that would work. Did find another way through locals which is probably the more correct way of doing it. Thanks!

Comment: Ah yes -- I forgot about `locals`.

Comment: It's awesome. Thank you.

Comment: I also needed to patch `render`

Answer (score 11):

Figured it out.

You can use locals in your middleware.

```
  app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.user = req.user;
    next();
  });
```

Then in the templates use.

```
<h1>User Name:{{user.name}}</h1>
```

<strike>`<h1>User Name:{{_locals.user.name}}</h1>`</strike>

Comment: You actually shouldn't use `_locals` in the template.  Express [automatically merges that internal variable into the top-level object](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/3.1.0/lib/application.js#L467-474).